# SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema and conditional SQL statements

Tags: c#, sql, schema, sqldataadapter

I'm creating application that **needs to retrieve SQL statement's schema** (actually the returned table's schema): the set of column names and corresponding SQL types.
The basic implementation is the following:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
sda.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
```

After that I parse the columns info of the DataTable.
Everything works fine until I try to use conditional statement in SQL and return data with different schema based on that condition. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestDataTable(Column1 int, Column2 nvarchar(100))

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TestDataTable)
BEGIN 
  SELECT Column1 FROM TestDataTable WHERE Column1>2 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
  SELECT Column2 FROM TestDataTable WHERE Column1>2 
END
```

The result is always Column1 in retrieved schema, not depending on condition in IF statement (when I invert it the result still the same).
Once more SQL-indicator is CASE statement in the SELECT clause - if they return different columns based on some condition, we get even more surprising results.

I tried different variants and options but every of them has it's own limitations:

1. *SqlDataAdapter.Fill();* - IF statemt evaluated correctly, but no way to get string types lengths
2. *sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);    SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable();* - IF statemt evaluated correctly, but no way to get string types lengths
3. *sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);    SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable();* - No way to get string types lengths. In addition it also returns schema assuming that every condition evaluates to True.

I found discussions of how the SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema() method works and looks like it is really complicated and generates some metadata-request SQL. So I'm really surprised that it works correctly even with dynamically generated SQL, like

```
DECLARE @selectPart1 nvarchar(100)
SET @selectPart1=N'SELECT Column1'
DECLARE @selectPart2 nvarchar(100)
SET @selectPart2=N'FROM TestDataTable'
DECLARE @selectQuery nvarchar(200)
SET @selectQuery = @selectPart1 + ' ' + @selectPart2

EXECUTE sp_executesql @selectQuery"
```

**But why can't it evaluate the IF condition, if it successfully evaluates the SET statements?**

**PS:** I understand that statements that return different data schema based on some condition is something unusual and hard to handle and it is definitely a bad-practice, but the SQL we'll get is user-provided and we should at least detect such inconsistent cases.

**As a workaround, a way to detect such cases (to show appropriate message to user) is also acceptable.**